# EFI Partition issue, single boot Mac

Tags: boot, mac

Got an old Mac and tried to load Ubuntu, however, after install on restart it wasnt booting giving black screen with blinking white cursor.  Tried Refind but it didnt help, found the link...

[EFI boot Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563401/efi-boot-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-mac-without-refind)

which made sense, given the Mac's EFI, however, when i got to step 4. Installing GRUB on the HFS Partition, i got the following message:

```
sudo grub-install --target x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform. grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition
```

Tried the troubleshoot option but still the same result.  I'm new to this, so still learning.  How can I resolve the issue of

```
grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

Comment: do you have the efi partition mounted?

Comment: not sure.. how can i check... sorry, very new to this

Comment: open gparted, it should show the partitions and where they are mounted.

Comment: doesnt seem like the partition is mounted.... how can i do that?

Comment: well is it mounted?

Comment: I cant seem to get it mounted