# Erase disk and install ubuntu mac

Tags: boot, mac, bios

I created a bootable ubuntu 18.04.1 and began the setup on my mac. I chose to delete everything on the computer by selecting `erase disk and install ubuntu`. The install went through without a hitch and then asked for a system restart, after removing the usb and rebooting I came to a screen `missing operating system`.

I'm not sure what to do next. Thanks for your help.

#### Addition 1

I have tried [EFI boot Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563401/efi-boot-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-mac-without-refind), and I think it's on the right track.

One of the files I need is `/boot/vmlinuz<extra stuff>.efi.signed`, I don't have that file, but I do have the file before adding `.efi.signed`.

When I run `linux /boot/vmlinuz〈extra stuff〉 root=UUID=〈UUID〉` I get `failure reading sector 0x4c146040 from hd2`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EFI boot Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563401/efi-boot-ubuntu-14-04-on-a-mac-without-refind)

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac?